# How to Set Spring Kafka consumer max attempts when using Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am developing Spring boot server with Spring kafka(1.3.2.RELEASE), apache avro(1.8.2) and io.confluent's Schema Registry(3.1.2). So evenytime the kafka listener gets a kafka message, it will find the schema id in message and get the avro schema from the registry server by id. The problem is, if the scheme registry config server is down, my listener will **keep trying** to send http request to the registry server to get the avro schema when it get a message(also prints large amount of error log), and it will block all the next kafka message since the offset won't **move on**.

```
16:56:41.541 ERROR KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer -  - org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 - Container exception
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition trade-0 at offset 810845
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 21
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:153)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:187)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:323)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:316)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:63)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getBySubjectAndID(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:118)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:121)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:92)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:54)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:918)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$2600(Fetcher.java:93)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1095)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1200(Fetcher.java:944)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:567)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:528)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1086)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1043)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:614)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried to use RetryTemplate to set the max attempts but it didn't work, It seems that the RetryTemplate may only works in my listener method. Also I didn't find any helpful config in the io confluent's website.

Answer (score 1):

Now I replace the KafkaAvroDeserializer by using a CustomAvroDeserializer, which extends the KafkaAvroDeserializer and override its deserialize method with adding a try-catch to its content, like this:

```
@Log4j
public class CustomAvroDeserializer extends KafkaAvroDeserializer {

  @Override
  public Object deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
    try {
      return this.deserialize(bytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("encounter a problem when deserializer message with schema registry:{}", e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```